# How to make it work about f[i] = max(f[i], f[i - 1] + f[i]) in dynamic programming?

Tags: c

**dynamic programming**
*here is a issue* 
The uppercase letters AZ correspond to the integers [-13,12], so a string corresponds to a whole column. We refer to the sum of the corresponding whole columns as the characteristic value of the string. For example: the overall column corresponding to the string ACM is {-13, -11, -1}, then the characteristic variable of the ACM (-13) + (-11) + (-1) = -25; the characteristics of its substring AC Variable -24; characteristic level -1 of substring M. Give you a string, find out the maximum feature value of all substrings of the string.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.H>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int n, f[1000];
    char s[1000];
    scanf("%d", &n);
    while(n--){
        int ans;
        scanf("%s", &s[0]);
        ans = f[0] = s[0] - 'A' - 13;
        for(int i = 1; i < strlen(s); ++i){
            f[i] = s[i] - 'A' - 13;
            f[i] = max(f[i], f[i - 1] + f[i]);  //I can't understand
            if(f[i] > ans)
                ans = f[i];
        }
        printf("%d\n", ans);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: that statement: `using namespace std;` is only valid in C++, NOT C.  The result is the posted code does not compile!

Comment: there is no `#include<algorithm>` header file in linux/C.  So this must be some 'home grown' header file.  You should post the contents of that file.  Home grown header files should be included via: `#include "algorithm"`  I.E. double quotes, not `<...>`

Comment: OT:  the posted code contains some 'magic' numbers. 'magic' numbers are numbers with no basis.  I.E. 13, 1000.  'magic' numbers make the code more difficult to understand, debug, etc.  Suggest using `#define` statements or a `enum` statement to give those 'magic' numbers meaningful names, then use those meaningful names throughout the code.

Comment: OT: regarding: `scanf("%s", &s[0]);`  1) always check the returned value (not the parameter values) to assure the operation was successful.  In the current scenario, any returned value other than 1 indicates an error occurred.   2)  when using the format specifiers `%s` and/or `%[...]` always include a max characters modifier that is 1 less than the length of the input buffer because those `input format conversion specifiers` always append a NUL byte to the input.  This also avoid any possibility of a buffer overflow and the attendant undefined behavior.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That line of code is setting the current index maximum value to the maximum of either the current letter, or the current letter added to the maximum of the previous index. This loop is getting the maximum value of a string up to each index. To get the total answer, you incrementally decide if you want to add the next letter to the previous maximum, or start a new substring. You update the golden answer `ans` if it is greater than before.

Comment: Thank you for your help.I think I gotta it.